# how to get the video from device and converted into byte

Tags: android

I want to get the video from device and want the video to be converted into byte as i want to send the data to server 
here is my code

```
if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        File file = new File(filePath.getPath());
        String s = file.getName();
        try {
            byte[] bytes1 = loadFile(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            Toast.makeText(CreateEmailCampaign.this, bytes1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

here is loadfile method

```
private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        long length = file.length();
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
                && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
        }

        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

it always shows

java.io.filenotfoundexception open failed enoent (no such file or directory)in android

Comment: check your file path

Comment: You might forgot to add the appropriate permission (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) to your Manifest.

Comment: I already provide the manifest permission

Comment: if you have any another way please provide me an example

Comment: log the value of `s` from this line `String s = file.getName();` what do you see ?

Comment: just shows the name of file

Comment: please give me some solution if anyone know it urgent